# How to count the number of rows in a table using a foreign key in the same query?

Tags: mysql, count, foreign-keys

Say I have *table1* which contains a field called *Name* and a field called *ItemID* which is a foreign key to *table2*.

What I want is a query that contains each Name, and how many entries in table2 have the same ItemID as that entry.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select Name, count(ItemID) as itemCount
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.ItemID = table2.id
group by Name
```

but my sql-fu may be rusty :P

Note that this will give no rows for Names where table2 contains no matching rows, so itemCould will always be >0

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted, thanks! Is there an easy way to modify to include rows where itemCount=0?

Comment: It is possible you could use a `left outer join` instead of the `inner join`, which will give null as ItemID for non-matching rows from table1, but I think then those nulls will be included in the count(), and that is not what you want. Anyone else?

Comment: I changed INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN and it worked exactly how I wanted it. Thanks heaps!